# vim-go: search for function specification rather than the declaration

Tags: go, vim

I have installed vim-go, and use ctrl+] to go to the definition. For a function, Sometimes it ends up in the interface declaration (if it was declared in an interface), but what I really intended to do was to go to function definition/specification. How can go to actual function definition?

Answer (score 0):

If `:GoDef` (which by default is mapped to `gd` and `CTRL-]`) doesn't work because it is a function in an interface, you can use `:GoImplements` to find implementations of that function. See the [vim-go tutorial](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go-tutorial#guru) for more.

Comment: Is `GoImplements` supposed to run when I place my cursor on the function call? When I do that, it gives me `vim-go: guru: no initial packages were loaded^@`

Comment: Yes, it should work that way. Is your GOPATH set up right?

Comment: See this vim-go issue for someone with a related problem: https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/1037